# How to parse rsync progress continuously in Golang?

Tags: go, rsync

The `exec.Command("rsync", "-ah --info=progress2 src dst")`  executes the `rsync`, which will produce the result below continuously:

```
3.76G 100%  515.60MB/s    0:00:06 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

So, How do I parse rsync progress continuously? Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
func CopyWithProgress(src, dst string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("rsync", fmt.Sprintf("-a --info=progress2 %s %s", src, dst))

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func(scanner *bufio.Reader) {
        percentMatcher := progress.NewMatcher(`(\d+\%)`)
        etaMatcher := progress.NewMatcher(`(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)`)
        speedMatcher := progress.NewMatcher(`(\d+\.\d+.{2}\/s)`)
    
        for scanner.Scan() {
            logStr := scanner.Text()
            fmt.Printf("Progress=%v\n", logStr)
        }
    }(bufio.NewScanner(stdout))

    if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But I can't get `scanner` to scan the output of rsync.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having parsing the output? (the command as shown is invalid, but that is irrelevant to parsing the output)

Comment: The problem is: cannot capture the output of `rsync --progress` continuously

Comment: does it happen to be on stderr ?

Comment: No, in `stdout`

Comment: soo what is happening ? You dont get any line ? Your regexp are failing ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the streaming output of a command : check [`Cmd.StdoutPipe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe), and the example code in the documentation.

To read a text output line by line : you can use a [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) (again, check the examples).